# Нужно ли тире: "Это была классная идея (-) разжечь костер"

Tags: пунктуация

"Это была классная идея разжечь костер" или "Это была классная идея — разжечь костер"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Это была классная идея — разжечь костер.

Обособление определения, выраженного инфинитивом,  делается в том случае, когда перед определяемым словом  находится согласованное определение, по отношению к которому несогласованное определение является пояснительным. Для обособления при этом используется не запятая, а ТИРЕ (тема присоединительных членов предложения, обособляемых с помощью тире):

Примеры:

Но прекрасен данный жребий – просиять и умереть. Мы все были одержимы одной страстью – сопротивляться. У человека есть одна обязанность – творить. Сбылась его давняя мечта – уехать в город.